# What weird encoding is movistar Venezuela sms on blackberry using?

Tags: blackberry, sms

Send an sms using the normal GSM TextMessage API on the BlackBerry, get back garbage. It's not unicode, phone is set to 7-bit send. Byte size is only off by one. Is there some default crypto thing, or some weird encoding they use? This code works most everywhere else in the world; this definitely seems like a movistar problem. The string that comes back is random 7-bit ascii except for a few high order bytes.

Needless to say the source input text is totally 7 bit chars, which should work in sms, ISO-8859 and look the same in UTF charsets.

Anybody seen this or got sms working in code on movistar VZ blackberries?

Comment: Maybe you could use some encoding guesser?
http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Encode-2.39/lib/Encode/Guess.pm

Python has BeautifulSoup also has one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example you can share?
It may be you are seeing the raw SMS data as stored on the blackberry. They will be sent / received in standard pdu format, but the blackberry itself will compress and possibly encrypt the data as well (depending on security settings)